# How RISCV architecture suggest to fill mtval register in instruction address fault?

Tags: exception, assembly, cpu-architecture, riscv

> If mtval is written with a nonzero value when a breakpoint, address-misaligned, access-fault, or page-fault exception occurs on an instruction fetch, load, or store, then mtval will contain the faulting virtual address.

> if mtval is written with a nonzero value when an instruction access-fault or page-fault exception occurs on a system with variable-length instructions, then mtval will contain the virtual address of the portion of the instruction that caused the fault, while mepc will point to the beginning of the instruction.

Those two explanations are taken from RISCV isa spec. I couldn't understand how to fill `mtval` in the instruction access fault. I thought at first it would always be equal to `mepc`, however, when a word instruction is misaligned(in the case C extension is applied so no instruction address misaligned exception) `mepc` and mtval should be different. It is because `mepc` will always be the instruction `PC` but mtval is the faulting portion. In this case, Since pmp address regions should be alligned to 4-byte, I expect `mtval` to be equal to either `mepc`+2, `mepc`, or `mepc`-2. However, this is not the case. When I tried the cases in `riscv-isa-sim`, it only set mtval to `mepc`+2 and `mepc`. When the second 2-byte of an instruction is allowed but not the first 2-byte mtval is not the portion of faulting virtual address but `PC` directly (it is misaligned to the 4-byte address.)

I know that I explained in a bit of a complex way but I think my concern is understandable. What am I missing to match `riscv-isa-sim` and spec explanations? Could you explain clearly how to fill mtval when an instruction access fault?

Comment: mepc is always the beginning of the instruction.  Whereas mtval is either that (e.g. the first 16 bits of the instruction cause the fault) or else the instruction is 32-bit and "misaligned" and crossing a page boundary, so the first 16 bits are not faulting while the rest are.  Seems to make sense to me.  If the first 16 bits are not allowed but the 2nd 16 bits are, that will fall into the category that mepc and mtval are equal.  There's no reason for the processor to inspect the last 16 bits if the first 16 bits fault.  What am I missing in your question?

Comment: Since spec says mtval contain faulting virtual address, I thought mtval in this exception should be word aligned because pmp regions should be word aligned. That's why showing mtval as lets say 0x12 seems wrong to me and it should be either 0x10 or 0x14.

Comment: It seems I understand the spec wrongly. So no need to think of faulting address as the official PMP region, but directly as the overlapping part of instruction in unallowed regions.